# why does j expression on an empty data.table produce output

Tags: r, data.table

1/29/18: opened an issue on this:
https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2590

I'm trying to understand if this is a bug or a feature. My understanding is that the j expression is evaluated for each row in the data table. Therefore, I expect an empty data.table to produce no output. In the 3 cases below, I don't understand why case 2 produces any output or why it produces warnings.

```
a <- data.table(foo = 0, bar = 1)
b <- a[1==2] #empty table
print("Test 1")
b[, .(foo, bar)] # expected output
print("Test 2")
b[, .(foo, bar, baz = "Hello")] #Unexpected output
print("Test 3")
b[1==2, .(foo, bar, baz = "Hello")] #expected output
```

Output:

```
[1] "Test 1"
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: foo,bar
[1] "Test 2"
     baz
1: Hello
Warning messages:
1: In as.data.table.list(jval) :
  Item 1 is of size 0 but maximum size is 1, therefore recycled with 'NA'
2: In as.data.table.list(jval) :
  Item 2 is of size 0 but maximum size is 1, therefore recycled with 'NA'
[1] "Test 3"
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: foo,bar,baz
```